# Return view on html button click

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm on ASP.NET and I want to navigate to another view when clicking on a button on the HTML page.

```
<input type="button" value="Back"  class="btn btn-default" />
```

That's my button and I want to make a:

```
return View();
```

Comment: Question unclear and does not contain any bit of research...

Comment: using a button to redirect to another view is a poor way of doing this because you have to hijack the button's click event. It would be better to use an anchor tag and style it to look like a button. Bootstrap has some classes for doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Your button needs to post back some data?

As the most basic response for your question is :

```
<input type="button" value="Back"  class="btn btn-default" onclick='window.location.href = @Url.Action("action","controller")' />
```

Which will redirect your page to your action.